# Shared experience in solidarity, describe mother's act, son can't eat before surgery, she decides to fast too, in solidarity and shared experience

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe a mother's act for her child, who is not allowed to eat before surgery and she chooses not to eat also, so I have thought of *solidarity* or *support*, but I want to also describe sharing this experience with her child.  They both feel the hunger together, the child must and the mother chooses.

> Mom was fasting in *solidarity* with her child who was NPO before the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***co-suffering*** but you could also combin it with *love*:

> Mom was fasting in ***co-suffering (love)*** with her child who was NPO before the procedure.

You will find ***co-sufferer*** in dictionaries with the meaning:

> One who suffers with another. ([FreeDict](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Co-sufferer))

This is in fact also the etymological meaning of *[compassion](https://www.etymonline.com/word/compassion)* (suffering with another), but this word is more used to describe a feeling, or state, not *taking action*, like *co-suffering* does.

Answer (score 0):

The words "solidarity" and "support" have connotations that are somewhat  too formal, I would say, but they might be used. Instead, I'd use the plain verb "to join".

> ([OAlD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/join_1?q=join)) ​ 
> [transitive] to take part in something that somebody else is doing or to go somewhere with them
> **join somebody**
> • Do you mind if I join you?
> **join somebody for something**
> • Will you join us for lunch?
> **join somebody + adv./prep**
> • They've invited us to join them on their yacht.
> • He joined her downstairs a few minutes later.
> **join something**
> • Over 200 members of staff joined the strike.
> •  Members of the public joined the search for the missing boy.
> **join somebody in doing something**
> • I'm sure you'll all join me in wishing Ted and Laura a very happy marriage.

- Mom **joined her child in fasting** so as to give strength to him  who was NPO before the procedure.

Comment: Thank you, I like "joined"

Comment: It depends on what tone you're going for: "solidarity" elevates the mother's suffering and makes her seem heroic and dignified, while "joined" makes it sound casual or minimal and not a noble act.

Comment: @StuartF I still believe "solidarity" is not quite appropriate: the SOED says "Unity or accordance of feeling, action, etc., esp. among individuals with _common interest, sympathies or aspirations_, as the members of a _Trade Union, social class, etc._; _mutual support_ or cohesiveness within a group.". The mother's behaviour does not involve real unity; the idea is rather that of encouragement or leadership. Also, perhaps the success of the operation can be called a "common" interest, but the immediate interest of the mother is in seeing that her son should be able to muster  (1/3)

Comment: @StuartF the energy to fast for as long as necessary. It is difficult to identify a truly common interest, that is, a common interrest as the definition would have it. As concerns the second part, the fact that there is no mutuality in the support, makes this part rather improper. // I do not find that the mother's behaviour could really be called heroic, noble, although "dignified" might apply, but rather, among other possible characterizations, I would favour the terms "tactful" and "sensible": (2/3)

Comment: @StuartF  a little fasting, especially of that sort that will not be detrimental to the more fragile constitution of a child, has never hurt anyone; on the contrary, I would say, it is healthful. (3/3)

Answer (score 0):

"Sympathetic" has a meaningful parallel in the sense that twins are said to have "sympathetic pain," (one quite literally experiences the suffering of the other) in that the Mother is undertaking the same trevail in an effort to comfort her child.  It may need some additional syntax to make it work but it makes for a powerful image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).